# Datatable date range function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

I have two datatables and I use four datepickers(`datepicker,datepicker2,datepicker3,datepicker4`). Two for each datatable. Actually it's working for one table but for the other it's not vice versa. Here is my code

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
   function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var mini =  document.getElementById('datepicker').value;
        var maxi =  document.getElementById('datepicker2').value;

        var mini2 =  document.getElementById('datepicker3').value;
        var maxi2 =  document.getElementById('datepicker4').value;

        if((mini !== '') && (maxi !== '')){
            var taena =  data[10]; // use data for the date column
            var ifMin = mini.substring(0,2) + mini.substring(3,5) + mini.substring(6,10);
            var ifMax = maxi.substring(0,2) + maxi.substring(3,5) + maxi.substring(6,10);
            var ifTaena = taena.substring(0,2) + taena.substring(3,5) + taena.substring(6,10);  

            if ( ( ifMin === '' && ifMax === '' ) || ( ifMin === '' && ifTaena <= ifMax ) || ( ifMin <= ifTaena && ifMax === '' ) || ( ifMin <= ifTaena && ifTaena <= ifMax ) ){
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        if((mini2 !== '') && (maxi2 !== '')){
             var taena2 =  data[9]; // use data for the date column
             console.log(taena2);
             var ifMin2 = mini2.substring(0,2) + mini2.substring(3,5) + mini2.substring(6,10);
             var ifMax2 = maxi2.substring(0,2) + maxi2.substring(3,5) + maxi2.substring(6,10);
             var ifTaena2 = taena2.substring(0,2) + taena2.substring(3,5) + taena2.substring(6,10);         

             if ( ( ifMin2 === '' && ifMax2 === '' ) || ( ifMin2 === '' && ifTaena2 <= ifMax2 ) || ( ifMin2 <= ifTaena2 && ifMax2 === '' ) || ( ifMin2 <= ifTaena2 && ifTaena2 <= ifMax2 ) ){
                return true;
             }
             return false;
        }
         return false;       
    }
);
```

I hope you guys could help me

Comment: Please provide the js fidlle link?

Comment: could u upload to jsfiddle

Comment: have you include this js "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.12/filtering/row-based/range_dates.js"

Comment: What error your getting at console

Comment: @DipakThoke my code is quite similar to that but I don't understand the two columns

Comment: Hi guys, sorry this is the  [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/k72ku3t1/3/). I change something on my code

Comment: nope & nope2 this two different varaible diferent datatable but draw only first both time check it

Comment: it sholud be lik this : $('#datepicker').change(function(){nope.draw();});
  $('#datepicker2').change(function(){nope.draw();});
  $('#datepicker3').change(function(){nope2.draw();});
  $('#datepicker4').change(function(){nope2.draw();});

Comment: Oh I didn't see that I already change but the second datatable only works

Comment: I change it [again](https://jsfiddle.net/k72ku3t1/7/) . The two works for the first run but when I tried to change the dates the other table is not working